# C++ Print Double without Integer Part

Tags: c++, output, double

If I have a double between 0 and 1, how can I print just the fractional part. So, for example, if I have the number `0.2342`, I would like to print `.2342`, not `0.2342`

Comment: This is not something people normally do, so you need to do it yourself. Convert it to a string, delete the first character. Done.

Comment: That is an interesting problem. I think the answer would be convert to string and ignore the first character.

Comment: @tadman looks like it's a common thing in the US. People usually omit the initial `0` there

Comment: @phuclv that really depends on the context in which the decimal value is being used.

Comment: @phuclv By a very unusual definition of "common". It's not something I've seen in widespread use.

Comment: @tadman not unusual at all. The default US locale setting doesn't print 0 in 0.xxx

Comment: @phuclv As someone who is in that locale, news to me.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one. Although, I think it's a little ugly.

```cc
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include <cassert>

std::string GetDecimal(float var)
{
    assert(var >= 0 && var <= 1.0f);
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << var;
    std::string str = ss.str();
    str.erase(str.begin());
    return str;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    float a;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::string str = GetDecimal(a);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I try it but I not sure it is what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string removeInteger(double num)
{
    int dec = num;
    double ret = num - dec;
    std::ostringstream strs;
    strs << ret;
    std::string retstr = strs.str().substr(1);
    return retstr;
}

int main()
{
    double num;

    std::cout << "Enter your number..." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> num;
    std::cout << "Result is " << removeInteger(num) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure that the `double` is between 0 and 1, *exclusive* then you can simply do:

```
double d = 0.2342;
std::cout << std::to_string(d).substr(1);  // prints .234200
```

If you don't want those trailing zeros, you can remove that from the output like this:

```
std::cout << std::to_string(d).substr(1, 5);  // prints .2342
```

Comment: `std::to_string(d)._c_str() +1`?

Comment: @user4581301 I'm not sure what advantage that has. It avoids creating a string, but I'm already using streams so there's not much to be gained in that regard.

Comment: Probably no merit whatsoever. One thing about `to_string` if I'm remembering correctly, is you'll also have to deal with the trailing zeros. Bets the asker wants those gone as well. Looked it up. It's based around `sprintf` and I'm not seeing any changes from `sprintf`'s default 6 character precision.

Comment: @user4581301 Hmm, good point. I edited the answer to work around that. I think that's probably sufficient for the OP's purposes.